# C++ I'm having doubts about the security of this function

Tags: c++

In my networking project, For simplicity, I'm using XOR encryption / decryption with a user defined key. I've come up with the following function.

```cpp
std::string XOR(std::string data, std::string encrypted_key) {

    char* key = new char [encrypted_key.length() + 1];
    strcpy (key, encrypted_key.c_str());
    std::string output = data;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        output[i] = data[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];
    }
    return output;
}
```

But I am having serious fears and doubts about the security of this. I fear that strcpy might cause a problem. Due to this I never even use the function, I use `snprintf` everytime. But here, it doesn't work. Can anyone confirm that is safe? Thanks! (Please excuse me if this is a silly question)

Comment: Why use `strcpy` at all? You can just do `output[i] = data[i] ^ encrypted_key[i % encrypted_key.size()];` One problem in your current code is that `sizeof(key)` won't give you the size of the array, or the `strlen` of `key`, it will give you the size of a `char*`, which is likely 8, or maybe 4 on your system. That means if `data.size() < 8` and `encrypted_key.size() < data.size()` you'll be XORing `data[i]` with potentially unknown data. So it's not unsafe, it's just incorrect. The memory leak is also an issue.

Comment: Oh, using c-string functions with your `encrypted_key` will also give you problems when your key contains any `0x00` byte. That will prematurely end the string. Only use the string functions on character strings. Don't use them on arbitrary byte strings.

Comment: If you really care about security don't roll your own encryption scheme.

Comment: This was modifying a XOR encryption function to fit my needs, Where I take the key is input by the user as string then used for later encryption. Looks like I didn't really understand the function. Apologies. I understand what @JohnFilleau means. I'm gonna do that. Thanks for showing me what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : After @JohnFilleau's comment, I've changed my function to this. I realized what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

```cpp
std::string XOR(std::string data, std::string encrypted_key) {
    std::string output = data;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
        output[i] = data[i] ^ encrypted_key[i % encrypted_key.size()];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: this isn't really an answer to your question, since you were asking about the safety of your function, not how to get your unshown `snprintf` function to work.

Comment: `std::string data` passes by value. This is a copy of whatever you used as an argument. `std::string output = data;` copies it again. Compiler's smart and will probably eliminate this redundancy, but you can get rid of output completely and `data[i] ^= encrypted_key[i % encrypted_key.size()];` and then  `return data;` `std::string encrypted_key` also passes by value. The compiler might also be able to clean this up, but if you pass by constant reference `const std::string & encrypted_key` no copy and no harm to the caller. Plus you can do a few other tricks with temporary objects.